# Sampling from distributions so that final distribution is log-normal

Tags: sampling

I have 5 groups of data, let's just say the income of people of 5 different tax brackets. Each group has 50 samples. I need to sample from these buckets without replacement so that the final distribution (Could be any number less than 250) is log-normal with a mean equal to the expected mean of all 250 samples. I don't care about the variance that much. How'd you do that?

Comment: Sampling from a finite population cannot produce a log-normal output.

Comment: @Xi'an but why is that?

Comment: A finite population of size $N$ cannot take more than $N$ distinct values, but a lognormal is a distribution with support over the whole positive half-line, $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: The same comment applies to any distribution with a continuous component and also to discrete ones with support on more than $N$ values. The best you can get is an approximation to the distribution function of the finite population.